# Opções de formatação de texto para HTML / PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

Gostaria de saber se possuí algum script ou algo relacionado onde eu possa adicionar em cima de minha text-area (Imagem 1) uma aba de formatações para o texto. Como é utilizado no próprio StackOverflow para criação de perguntas (Imagem 2).

Imagem 1
[image: Imagem 1]

Imagem 2

[image: Imagem 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem sim!

Eu gosto de usar o [Froala Editor](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor)

Após adicionar todas as dependências ao seu projeto, basta setar seu textarea como um input que utilizará a biblioteca do editor.

Suponha que você tenha um textarea assim:

```
<textarea id="resumoAtividades"></textarea>
```

Você só precisará fazer isso em seu JS:

```
<script>
        $(function() {
                $('textarea#resumoAtividades').froalaEditor()
        });
</script>
```

Mas existem várias outras alternativas:

O [CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5-builds/) também é super conhecido, é OpenSource e a forma de se usar é similar ao Froala.

Para encontrar outras alternativas, procura por `textarea editor` no Google.

Comment: O que estou fazendo é depois exportar o que foi escrito em PDF, para manter a formatação feita ele aceita o <pre> ?

Comment: @MatheusMartins, você consegue fazer isso tranquilo! Eu não sei te dar certeza se na versão free do Froala eles permitem usar o <pre>, mas na pior das hipóteses, você adiciona manualmente. De qualquer forma, existem ferramentas similares, gratuitas que fazem a mesma coisa que o Froala, atualizei a resposta dando outras alternativas.

Comment: Ah certo, estava procurando isto faz tempo, porém eu não achei nada a respeito, pesquisava por formatação porém só aparecia coisas como formatação de texto por tags haha. Obrigado.